# How can I use physics connect functions in Blender 2.8?

Tags: physics, constraints

I've been taking tutorials of Blender at the age of 2.79(we still live in this age basically), and I am pretty used to the physics tool bar functions in 2.79, you can create physical constraints between a bunch of object for example. I used to made caterpillar track with that function at that time. 
However in 2.80 when I find connect inside the object menu, it just doesn't work.
[image]
[image: what happens after I hit connect]

Answer (score -1):

you need to create an empty and go to physic tab and add constraint ! the empty is the link between 2 rigid body object :)